# How to register IoT devices with Swift

Tags: swift, arduino, raspberry-pi, iot

I want to build an IoT app that connects devices and show sensors data. If I want users to register their device, I assume that I have to give each device UUID and let the user enter that UUID. If the UUID is valid and doesn’t overlap with other devices, then the user successfully register the device.

Assuming I am on the right track, should I make a list of arrays of devices and check if the user entered a valid UUID in the array?

```
//Textfield where user enters their device ID
@IBOutlet weak var deviceIdTextfield: UITextField!

//I created a list of device array for example...
let deviceArray = ["device1", "device2", "device3", "device4", "device5"]

//If the user enters the device ID and press the button it checks if the ID is in the list of device array
@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    deviceIdTextfield.text = deviceArray[0]
    print("success")}
```

My question is, First, is this the right way to approach making IoT apps?
Second, in the IBAction func, is there a way to check if my users device's ID is within my array? rather than giving a specific order like deviceArray[0].

Any advice or comments would be really helpful :)

Comment: To check if entered UUID is in the list: `if let deviceId = deviceIdTextfield.text, deviceArray.contains(deviceId) { print("device is known") }`

Comment: that sloved my question 100% thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if entered UUID is in the list you can do this:

```
if let deviceId = deviceIdTextfield.text, 
    deviceArray.contains(deviceId) { 
    print("device is known") 
}
```